# How can I check if all elements of array doesn't equal to some value? (e.g. not empty)

Tags: java, arrays

Array before.

```
  String[] player = {"Empty","Empty","Empty","Empty"}
```

Array after input.

```
String[] player = {"Tom","Bob","Alex","Kid"}
```

I remember there was a way to check all of the elements of the array.

```
if(!player[0].equals("Empty") && !player[1].equals("Empty") && !player[2].equals("Empty") && !player[3].equals("Empty"))
{
   System.out.println("No more space");
}
```

My question. Is there a way to select all of the elements of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the array *implicitly*:

```
if(!Arrays.asList(player).contains("Empty"))
   System.out.println("No more space.");
```

or iterate over the array *explicitly*:

```
for(String p : player)
{
    if(!p.equals("Empty"))
       continue;
    else
    {
       System.out.println("No more space.");
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if array is `{"Empty", "Empty", "Empty", "Empty"}` this will output "No more space" four times? Why don't you add break?

Comment: Is there any other way? without using for loop. Im not sure but i remember i read in a book that there is array.all or something like that. Not sure that's why im asking.

Comment: @om-nom-nom sorry dude, I omitted it, I was dealing with the second solution =(

Comment: well all this are not bad, but its not what i wanted. Well I will have to read the book again. To see if I was mistaken

Comment: Found it. my mistake it was for ArrayList. oh well thx anyways =D

Comment: Hey Del dude ... your loop would look a lot less ugly if you refactored to get rid of the "!".

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
boolean hasEmpty = false;

for (int i = 0; i < player.length(); i ++)
{
     if(player[i].equals("Empty")){
         hasEmpty = true;
         break;
     }
}

if(hasEmpty) System.out.println("No more space");
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this might not be an option, but [in Java 8 you could do](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html):

```
boolean nonEmpty = Arrays.asList(player).anyMatch(x -> x.equals("Empty"))
```

Comment: True ... but I can't see how that is an improvement over the `contains` solution.  (And it is likely to be slower, if anything)

Comment: Now if the problem required a case insensitive match, things would be different ...

Comment: @StephenC why do you think this will be slower? allMatch short-circuiting (exits on the first "false")? Or you're worry about invoke-dynamic?